# Replace set of values with single value and sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have [a table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac2c5) as follows:

```
id  group1  group2  is_bar  amount
1   a       bar1    true    100
2   a       bar2    true    200
3   a       baz     false   150
4   a       baz     false   250
5   b       bar1    true    50
```

Every time `is_bar` is true, I'd like to replace the value in `group2` and sum over `amount` resulting in:

```
group1  group2  amount
a       bar     300
a       baz     400
b       bar     50
```

I currently do this using a subquery and then grouping by *every other column in the table*! But this seems a bit noob to me:

```
SELECT group1, group2, sum(amount) FROM 
(
  SELECT group1,
  CASE WHEN is_bar THEN 'bar' ELSE group2 END as group2,
  amount
  FROM foo
) new_foo
GROUP BY group1, group2
ORDER BY group1, group2;
```

Is there a smart-person solution to this?

Comment: Not sure why you need the subquery -- I think you could just `SELECT group1, CASE ... END, sum(amount) FROM foo` at the top level and use column *numbers* to GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT
    group1
    , CASE WHEN is_bar THEN 'bar' ELSE group2 END as group2 
    , SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM foo
GROUP BY group1, CASE WHEN is_bar THEN 'bar' ELSE group2 END
```

As @Patrick has mentioned in the comments you can replace the very long conditions in the `GROUP BY` with a `GROUP BY 1, 2`.

This will automatically refer to columns 1 and 2 (first and second) in the `SELECT` statement and the query will have the same output. But, if you add a different column as the first, you will have to make sure the `GROUP BY` still works as intended by changing or adding a number/condition representing the first column.

Comment: I would make that a `GROUP BY 1, 2`.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, it would be simpler, but the logic change wouldn't be as obvious.

Comment: I didn't know you could use column numbers in `GROUP BY`. The repeating of the `CASE` statement makes me nervous and is not very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in Postgresql you *can* `GROUP BY` an aliased column, as stated in [this part of the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html):

> In strict SQL, GROUP BY can only group by columns of the source table
>   but PostgreSQL extends this to also allow GROUP BY to group by columns
>   in the select list. Grouping by value expressions instead of simple
>   column names is also allowed.

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac2c5/10) shows that in action:

```
SELECT
    group1,
    CASE WHEN is_bar THEN 'bar' ELSE group2 END group2_grouped,
    SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM foo
GROUP BY group1, group2_grouped
```

The problem arises when you try to alias the `CASE` statement to the same as the column name as Postgresql will `GROUP BY` the original column *not* the alias. This is mentioned in [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

> In case of ambiguity, a GROUP BY name will be interpreted as an
>   input-column name rather than an output column name.